# Error in printing bind variables in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to print bind variable in PL/SQL. Upon executing the code, a new window pops up asking me to enter a value for the same. Submitting my response takes me to the previous page and I get an error `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`. 
I am using Oracle Database 10g Express Edition.

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Here's the code for your reference:

```
VARIABLE v_bind VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    :v_bind:='Hello';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:v_bind);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Submitting response"? "Previous page"? Which tool do you use?

In SQL*Plus, it works as expected:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> var v_bind varchar2(10);
SQL> begin
  2    :v_bind := 'Hello';
  3    dbms_output.put_line(:v_bind);
  4  end;
  5  /
Hello

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```